# Unknown buffer size to be read from a DataInputStream in java

Tags: java, io, inputstream, datainputstream

I have the following statement:

`DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(process.getInputStream());`

I would like to print the contents of this input stream but I dont know the size of this stream. How should I read this stream and print it?

Comment: If you only use a buffer, using a DataInputStream doesn't add any value.

Answer (score 8):

It is common to all Streams, that the length is not known in advance. Using a standard `InputStream` the usual solution is to simply call `read` until `-1` is returned.

But I assume, that you have wrapped a standard `InputStream` with a `DataInputStream` for a good reason: To parse **binary** data. (Note: `Scanner` is for textual data only.)

The [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) for `DataInputStream` shows you, that this class has two different ways to indicate EOF - each method either returns `-1` or throws an `EOFException`. A rule of thumb is:

- Every method which is inherited from `InputStream` uses the "return `-1`" convention,
- Every method **NOT** inherited from `InputStream` throws the `EOFException`.

If you use `readShort` for example, read until an exception is thrown, if you use "read()", do so until `-1` is returned.

Tip: Be **very** careful in the beginning and lookup each method you use from `DataInputStream` - a rule of thumb can break.

Comment: +1 The [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/datastreams.html) elaborates, "Notice that `DataStreams` detects an end-of-file condition by catching `EOFException`, instead of testing for an invalid return value."

Comment: I thought, I made the distinction between DIS and IS clear. But I edited the answer according to your input. TNX

Comment: Aha, methods implementing `DataInput`, which are _not_ inherited from `InputStream`, throw `EOFException`. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

Call [`is.read(byte[])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) repeadely, passing a pre-allocated buffer (you can keep reusing the same buffer). The function will return the number of bytes actually read, or -1 at the end of the stream (in which case, stop):

```
byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
int nread;
while ((nread = is.read(buf)) >= 0) {
  // process the first `nread` bytes of `buf`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
int numberRead = 0;
do{
   numberRead = is.read(buffer);
   if (numberRead != -1){
      // do work here
   }
}while (numberRead == buffer.length);
```

Keep reading a set buffer size in a loop. If the return value is ever less than the size of the buffer you know you have reached the end of the stream. If the return value is -1, there is no data in the buffer.

[DataInputStream.read](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score -1):

`DataInputStream` is something obsolete. I recommend you to use `Scanner` instead.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (process.getInputStream());
while (sc.hasNextXxx()) {
   System.out.println(sc.nextXxx());
}
```

Comment: Not sure DataInputStream is obsolete, but it is redundant here.